# In SQL Server when a table is transferred to another schema is it possible to know the original schema of the table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Motivation - I need to record all the schema changes concerning tables. So, adding/dropping/altering/renaming tables is easily tracked through the corresponding DDL triggers. When a table is renamed, its original name is mentioned in the result of the `EVENTDATA()` function.

But, when a table is transferred to another schema - bad luck. For the reasons that escape me the result of `EVENTDATA()` does not mention the original schema of the table.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am scared that you move objects between schemas so regularly that you need to audit it.

Comment: I think I would echo Sean here. If there isn't a built-in way to monitor it, you might want to look at why you're doing it to begin with.

Comment: Really not often at all. Still, it happens sometimes and I want to be aware of it.

Comment: I assume that in your DDL trigger the schema has already changed ? So quering it from the system tables in that trigger will be to late ?

Comment: Indeed. And it does not seem possible to have BEFORE ALTER_SCHEMA

Comment: How about making a report by querying drop and creation datetimes of same-name tables among all tracked schemas?  If the drop time of schema A is identical or similar to the creation time of schema B with the same table name, then voila, you have found a table moved from one schema to another schema.

Comment: There is no drop event when a table is transferred.